# what is the difference between == and -eq in an if statement?

Tags: bash, shell

Having the following for simplicity:

```
while
    echo -n "Does the command include flag(s)? (Y/N): "
    read option
    echo "option: '${option}'"

    # Is mandatory use `==` and NOT `-eq`
    if [[ $option -eq "y" || $option -eq "n" || $option -eq "Y" || $option -eq "N" ]]; then
      echo "Valid option"
      break;
    else
      echo "Invalid option"
    fi
  do :; done
```

If an input of a number is applied it works how is expected: *Invalid option* appears, but when any character is used how input always *Valid option* appears and it is not correct, but if is used (observe now `==` is used and not `-eq`)

```
while
    echo -n "Does the command include flag(s)? (Y/N): "
    read option
    echo "option: '${option}'"

    # Is mandatory use `==` and NOT `-eq`
    if [[ $option == "y" || $option == "n" || $option == "Y" || $option == "N" ]]; then
      echo "Valid option"
      break;
    else
      echo "Invalid option"
    fi
  do :; done
```

All work how is expected from the beginning.

So what is the difference between `==` and `-eq` in an `if` statement?